# Can't seem to emit custom event with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

Alright guys so i'm stuck on this and can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I'm still relatively new to using socket.io and was hoping someone with more experience can help me out. I added an event listener for 'typing' so when a user is typing it broadcasts it to the room like so `user` is typing...

on my 'bindSocketEvents' server side i have the following

```
//nickname is already set 
socket.emit('typing', { nick: nickname });
```

and then in my 'bindDOMEvents` function i have

```
socket.on('typing', function(data){
    $('<li>' + data.nick + ' is typing...</li>').appendTo('.chat-rooms ul li');
});
//dont mind what its appending to i am just trying to get it working
```

my event doesn't seem to be emitted though and socket.on 'typing' is never fired

Comment: Are you sure your bindDOMEvents function getting called?

Comment: yup everything else is working handling messages and joining rooms

Comment: use `console.log(nickname+" is typing");` on server and something similar on client side. Is it the server that is not sending the event? is it the client that is not capturing it? You can find out this with console.log. Also another question, how can the server know that `nickname` is typing? another event there?

Comment: alright I'll try that, here is the source and live app
http://appchat.aws.af.cm/scripts/chat.io.js

Comment: thanks for the recommendation ended up solving it myself by using console.log

Comment: What was your solution?